# Interfacing DF Robot Bluetooth module with Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

How can the DF Robot Bluetooth module be connected to the Arduino so that the Arduino can communicate with it.

I used [this tutorial](http://yerobot.com/download/mannual/DF-Bluetooth%20Manual.pdf).

I managed to get the light flashing on the module and it seems to be able to pair fine, but when I run the serial monitor and send a letter (say 'H') which should turn a light on I get a Java error:

```
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor in nativeDrain 
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort.nativeDrain(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialOutputStream.flush(RXTXPort.java:1201)
at processing.app.Serial.write(Serial.java:470)
at processing.app.Serial.write(Serial.java:492)
at processing.app.SerialMonitor.send(SerialMonitor.java:128)
at processing.app.SerialMonitor.access$100(SerialMonitor.java:29)
at processing.app.SerialMonitor$4.actionPerformed(SerialMonitor.java:82)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I checked the wiring and I have the RXD going to the RX (pin 0) on the board and TXD to TX (pin 1) and the rest wired up, but again still no luck. What could be the matter?

This is the code I have on the Arduino:

```
int ledpin = 13;
char val;
void setup() {
    pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT); // pin 48 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
    Serial.begin(9600); // start serial communication at 9600bps
}

void loop() {
    if( Serial.available() ) { // if data is available to read
        val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in 'val'
    }

    if( val == 'H' ) { // if 'H' was received
        digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH); // turn ON the LED
    } else {
        digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW); // otherwise turn it OFF
    }

    delay(100); // wait 100ms for next reading
}
```

Comment: Are you able to connect the Arduino directly to the serial port and get the communication to work (i.e. without having the Bluetooth module in the mix)?

Comment: yeah its just seems the bluetooth doesn't like the the arudio IDE connection libary

Comment: Please could you detail the components (Arduino IDE, serial port, Bluetooth module, Arduino, etc.) and the communication mechanisms between them (serial, bluetooth, etc.)? In particular I'm not clear how sending data to the serial port gets converted to a bluetooth signal and picked up by the module.

Comment: Basically I have  the follwoing 
.Freeduino with atmega 168 chip
.Arduino IDE 17
.The DF robot Bluetooth module
.Transferring code through USB Serial then connecting to battery to work with BT
.A bluetooth com port set up on COM9 as outgoing connection
.also if any help if i make a simple c# app to communicate to the com portthis works however i cannot do this useing the ardunio IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that a dodgy power supply to the Arduino/Bluetooth module could cause this error (i.e. it could be related to the error reported in [this Arduino Forum Topic](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1182734163)).

Comment: hmm yeah i suppose however how can i get it working a custom C# app but not the standard

Comment: It may depend on if the .NET library and the gnu.io.RXTXPort code handle losing the connection differently (e.g. reestablishing the connection versus closing the associated file descriptor)?

Comment: after some investigation It seemed this was the case I tried another arduino and seemed to work fine thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your RXTX library to the latest version. IIRC the Arduino IDE comes bundled with a version of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but...

The example in the linked tutorial uses a baud rate of 115200 (rather than the 9600 used in your example) and says:

> Check the serial setting! Make sure
>   the baud rate is set to 115200 on both
>   master and slave.

It could be that either:

- This only works with a baud rate of 115200 (which seems unlikely) or possibly
- The baud rate on the master and slave is not 9600

Comment: Hi I have tried this however still no luck thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Yes, and nothing came through so I thought i'd try sending data then I can truley make sure

Answer (score 1):

You should connect the Rx from the Bluetooth module to the Tx on the Arduino board, and vice versa. Or did you do so already? Hang it on a 12 V adapter power supply to be sure the power is not the issue. (One with 500 mA should be fine.)

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible problems.

First possible problem:

You have it wired wrong or you have described your wiring wrong. Usually, you connect the RX from the BT module to the TX on the Arduino and the TX on the BT to the RX on the Arduino.

Second possible problem:

You cannot connect to the Bluetooth module and then use the inbuilt serial monitor app to monitor the serial port on the Arduino.  I'm not sure of your hardware, but usually you cannot have them both connected as they are the same serial port.

Disconnect the Arduino from the PC.  Power up the Arduino from some other source.  Connect the PC to the BT module.  Run your fav TTY app on the PC (tera term is nice) and connect to the BT module COM port and type 'H'.

Let me know what you get!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar troubles in establishing communication from PC to GSM Modem via serial port. I was first working with java.comm on vista and it was impossible. Later, I switched to RxTxComm and it was a lot more reliable. Use it instead.

Comment: I am using the arduino IDE so i have no choice on what port connection it uses, also have looking it does use ...RXTXPort$SerialOutputStream.flush(RXTXPort...

Comment: My bad. I went straight to the code and didn't see any RxTx like commands so I posted it. nvm.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Bluetooth Mate Silver with my Arduino and the following link is what I used to manage my Bluetooth communication.

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port

I had to import the RXTX library from here:

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port

Also like other users have stated, use a baud rate of 115200, and connect the

Bluetooth-RX line --> Arduino-TX line, and

Bluetooth-TX line --> Arduino-RX line

The first link was a major breakthrough for me. Hope it helps you.